# incremental-update to feature in sharepoint by powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

New to `PowerShell` and `SharePoint`, i have a `sharepoint 2013` project on `visual studio 2013`  that contains a SharePoint List definition and instance.

After adding and installing the solution and enabling the feature, i added too many records to the list.

Now i added another column to the list (business need) and i want to update the feature (`PowerShell`) without loosing the records inserted before...

ps: Every time i deploy(after adding the new column), a message from VS is shown : `The url or name of this list instance conflicts with a list instance already on the server, the list instance on the server will be deleted before deploying the new instance`... and i click on `Resolve automatically` – then the list content disappears...

How can i do this please?

Comment: Hi new user, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for more clarifications... i found that it was not very complicated...
To perform such update

> 1/ In Production environment :

Just need to run `Update-SPSolution` cmd-let and this will do the job for you...

Or we can do the following too

1-Deactivating feature ...

2-Retracting solution ...

3-Deleting solution ...

4-Adding solution ...

5-Deploying solution ...

6-Activating feature ...

> 2/ In Dev environment :

You can set the `Deployment Conflict Resolution` property of the list instance in the Solution Explorer to `None`. Simply right-click on the list instance project item in VS and select Properties. Then select None from the dropdown list

Here is a link for more informations: http://michaelbrockman.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/deployment-conflict-resolution-in-visual-studio/